# Pip using proxy even when proxy disabled

Tags: python, proxy, pip

So I operate my pc on a college based network using a proxy server. So for using pip I tried a lot of things to implement the proxy tunneling for pypip as well. 
But I kept getting the same kind of error,so I tried removing the proxy, connecting to a non college wifi and trying it again. But somehow it's stuck on using the same proxy address again and again, even though i've turned off the proxy in windows proxy settings.

```
    Exception:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\users\deepa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\cli\base_command.py", l
    ine 179, in main
        status = self.run(options, args)
      File "c:\users\deepa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\commands\install.py", l
    ine 315, in run
        resolver.resolve(requirement_set)
      File "c:\users\deepa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\resolve.py", line 131,
    in resolve
        self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req)
      File "c:\users\deepa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\resolve.py", line 294,
    in _resolve_one
        abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
      File "c:\users\deepa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\resolve.py", line 242,
    in _get_abstract_dist_for
        self.require_hashes
      File "c:\users\deepa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\operations\prepare.py",
     line 269, in prepare_linked_requirement
        req.populate_link(finder, upgrade_allowed, require_hashes)
      File "c:\users\deepa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\req\req_install.py", li
    ne 196, in populate_link
        self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
      File "c:\users\deepa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\index.py", line 639, in
     find_requirement
        all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
      File "c:\users\deepa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\index.py", line 610, in
     find_all_candidates
        for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
      File "c:\users\deepa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\index.py", line 743, in
     _get_pages
        page = _get_html_page(location, session=self.session)
      File "c:\users\deepa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\index.py", line 229, in
     _get_html_page
        resp = _get_html_response(url, session=session)
      File "c:\users\deepa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\index.py", line 177, in
     _get_html_response
        "Cache-Control": "max-age=0",
      File "c:\users\deepa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\requests\sessions.py", li
    ne 546, in get
        return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
      File "c:\users\deepa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\download.py", line 403,
     in request
        return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
      File "c:\users\deepa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\requests\sessions.py", li
    ne 533, in request
        resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
      File "c:\users\deepa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\requests\sessions.py", li
    ne 646, in send
        r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
      File "c:\users\deepa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\cachecontrol\adapter.py",
     line 53, in send
        resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
      File "c:\users\deepa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\requests\adapters.py", li
    ne 412, in send
        conn = self.get_connection(request.url, proxies)
      File "c:\users\deepa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\requests\adapters.py", li
    ne 309, in get_connection
        proxy_manager = self.proxy_manager_for(proxy)
      File "c:\users\deepa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\requests\adapters.py", li
    ne 199, in proxy_manager_for
        **proxy_kwargs)
      File "c:\users\deepa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\urllib3\poolmanager.py",
    line 450, in proxy_from_url
        return ProxyManager(proxy_url=url, **kw)
      File "c:\users\deepa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\urllib3\poolmanager.py",
    line 401, in init
        raise ProxySchemeUnknown(proxy.scheme)
    pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.ProxySchemeUnknown: Not supported proxy scheme adityaga
```

Comment: The proxy may be persisted in the `%APPDATA%\pip\pip.ini` or as an environment variable.

Comment: @hoefling There exist no such file in either of the 3 directories in AppData. There is a pip folder in AppData\Local, but there is no .ini file in it.

Comment: Try creating a venv 
under venv\Scripts folder put the pip.ini file with proxy setting